How to remove as much direct relationship as possible, but keeping the same boss//employees relationships
Here's the problem: There is a company with N people, there are M direct relationships. When person 3 is directly/indirectly under 2, and 2 is directly/indirectly under 1, 3 is indirectly under 1. I can remove a direct relationship, if that direct relationship turns into an indirect one, but not if it is completely removed. I need to remove as much direct relationships as possible, then return the new number of direct relationships.
The input is: the first line is 2 number N and M, and the next M lines is 2 numbers a and b, meaning b is working directly under a.
Example test case:
Input:
5 8
3 5
1 4
4 3
1 3
4 5
1 2
1 5
2 3
Output: 5
In this test case, we remove the 1 3 (because of 1 > 2 > 3), 1 5 (because of
1 > 2 > 3 > 5) and 4 5 (because of 4 > 3 > 5) so there are 5 remaining direct relationship
#include<fstream>
#include<set>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

struct relationship {
    set<int> direct;
    set<int> indirect;
};


bool check(set<int> a, int b) {
    bool t = 0;
    for (int i: a) {
        if (b==i) {
            t=1;
        }
    }
    return t;
}

int main() {
    ifstream fi;
    fi.open("input.inp");
    ofstream fo;
    fo.open("output.out");
    map<int,relationship> relationships;
    int n,m,b,e;
    fi >> n >> m;
    while (fi >> b >> e) {
        relationships[b].direct.insert(e);
        for (int i : relationships[e].direct) {
            relationships[b].indirect.insert(i);
        }
        for (int i : relationships[e].indirect) {
            relationships[b].indirect.insert(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int k : relationships[i].direct) {
            if (check(relationships[i].indirect,k)) {
                m-=1;
            }
        }
    }
    fo << m;
    return 0;
}

This is my current code. I will check if one is both directly and indirectly under another person, if yes minus one to the number of indirect relationships. However, I can't add all the indirect relationships.

bool check(set<int> a, int b) { you don't need to pass the set by value. A const reference would likely be more efficient.

Side note : for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) can also be a range  based for loops

What is an example test case for this code and the expected and actual output for that case?

@RetiredNinja hi I've added a test case in my post. Thx for noticing me

When you wrote next N lines, did you mean next M lines? If so, you should correct that.

I’m voting to close this question because this seems more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms


I can't add all the indirect relationships.

You can if you change two things.

Don't mix reading the input and looking for the relations; rather read the whole input first:
    while (fi >> b >> e)
        relationships[b].direct.insert(e);


The way you're looking for the relations finds only simple indirect ones; one way to find double or higher indirect ones is repeating until no new indirect ones are found:
    int old, now;   // indirect relations
    do
    {   old = 0, now = 0;
        for (auto &m: relationships)    // all relations
        {
            old += m.second.indirect.size();
            for (int e: m.second.direct)    // relations of one boss
            {
                int b = m.first;
                for (int i: relationships[e].direct)
                    relationships[b].indirect.insert(i);
                for (int i: relationships[e].indirect)
                    relationships[b].indirect.insert(i);
            }
            now += m.second.indirect.size();
        }
    } while (old < now);



